# How can i runs second animation after first animation?

Tags: android, animation, touch

I have 2animation and i want first, my background shows with first animation and when first animation finished then my 4 buttons shows with second animation. background and buttons are in one XML file.  and i want when animation is runs, onTouch() method not work.

I searched and say use AnimationListener but i can't use this!

this is my code, please read and help me

```
public class Splash extends Activity {

Animation animation1;
Animation animation2;
Animation animation3;
ImageView image;
ImageButton circleProduct;
ImageButton circleIntroduce;
ImageButton circleMore;
ImageButton circleContact;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    animation1=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.bounce);
    animation1.setAnimationListener(this);
    animation2=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.push_left_out);
    animation2.setAnimationListener(this);
    animation3=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.push_left_out);
    animation3.setAnimationListener(this);

    image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
    image.startAnimation(animation1);

    circleProduct=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnCircleProduct);
    circleIntroduce=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnCircleIntroduce);
    circleMore=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnCircleMore);
    circleContact=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnCircleContact);

    circleProduct.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    circleProduct.startAnimation(animation2);
    circleContact.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    circleContact.startAnimation(animation2);
    circleIntroduce.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    circleIntroduce.startAnimation(animation3);
    circleMore.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    circleMore.startAnimation(animation3);

    image.setOnTouchListener(onTouchListener);
    circleProduct.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
}

private OnTouchListener onTouchListener=new OnTouchListener(){
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i("clicked", "on the Splas");
        Intent intent=new Intent(Splash.this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        //finish();
        return false;
    }
};

private OnClickListener onClickListener=new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i("circuleProduct", "clicked");
        Intent intent=new Intent(Splash.this,Product.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

};

 }
```

Thanks

Comment: What is happening can you explain a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add animationListner to the first animation and start the second animation in its onAnimationEnd method

try the code below

remove other animation listners

```
animation1.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

        public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            yourView.startAnimation(animation2);
        }
    });
```

hope it will help you.

Comment: i just saw it @SensorS, what was the problem?